# Pasar datos dinamicamente de un DataGridView a otro DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

quiero pasar los datos de un datagridview1 a otro datagridview2 presionando un boton,pero quiero que se pasen todos los datos seleccionados.hasta el momento solo consigo que pasen los registros  uno por uno por uno, es decir una fila.mi problema es que no logro que pasen todos los datos presionando el boton "pasartodo"
si alguien me puede ayudar  estare muy agradecida,

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] {
    Convert.ToString(dataGridView2[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value),
    Convert.ToString(dataGridView2[1, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value) 
    Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[2, dgvRegistro.CurrentRow.Index].Value) 
});

dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index);
```

Comment: Buenas andrea, si he entendido bien quieres tener un boton que pase dinamicamente TODOS los datos de un datagrid a otro. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿O quieres que sea un conjunto de datos seleccionados? Por otro lado, ¿De donde provienen los datos cargados en el datagridview1 de una base de datos? los añades manualmente?

Comment: Si ya sabes como pasar una fila, pasar todas es sencillo.Debes hacer un bucle que recorra todas las filas del datagridview1 y las pase al dos. Algo como `for (int i=0;i<datagridview1.Rows.Count;i++)...`

Comment: la respuesta depende si los grids tenen asignado un origen de datos, o sea si asignas el DataSource o no

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el `foreach` para iterar las rows seleccionadas usando algo como esto

```
List<DataGridViewRow> items = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach(var row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    items.Add(row);
}

foreach(var item in items)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] {
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[0].Value),
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[1].Value),
            Convert.ToString(item.Cells[2].Value) 
        });

    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(item);
}
```

Se usa una lista temporal porque el foreach no permite remover mientras iteras

Comment: buenas Leandro gracias por tu respuestas pero al probar tu condigo me da error en el primer foreach.

Comment: sale error en la linea  items.Add(row);   para especificar. es solo eso, si pudieras ayudarme. te agradezco